# PyInstaller: Where can I find output from my application (nothing displays in the console)?

Tags: pyinstaller

I have built a single file executable of my Python application using PyInstaller version 3.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.

When I launch the executable on the same system where I've built it (in order to verify that all went as advertised) it returns me to the command line prompt after a couple of seconds. It appears that *something* is happening but there is no output to the console as expected. I've also tried to redirect output and error to a file but nothing goes there either. For example:

```sh
$ dist/myapp >> log.txt 2>&1
$ cat log.txt
$
```

Normally the application logs information to the console as it's running.

Where can I look for information as to what is happening when I launch the executable that PyInstaller has created (i.e. where's my stdout/stderr going)? Also, I've rebuilt my executable using the `--debug all` option but this appears to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling the debug option:

```
--log-level=DEBUG
```

Source: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html

You can also use command ‘strace’.

See the guide: https://www.tecmint.com/strace-commands-for-troubleshooting-and-debugging-linux/

Comment: Thanks, @Kevin. The logging level appears to affect only the build process, which in my case appears to work fine. The trouble comes when I run the single file executable application that's been built -- there is no output of any kind and after a couple of seconds it seems to stop and returns me to the command line prompt. I can't determine what's going wrong without output of some kind from which to diagnose the problem. Good times...

Comment: When I run the `strace` command suggested in the PyInstaller documentation for when things go wrong I don't see anything obviously amiss:
```
strace: Process 19827 attached

[pid 19827] +++ exited with 0 +++

--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=19827, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=8, si_stime=2} ---

+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the program itself, or the way it's compiled. I see it doesn't show any error.
Create a new issue in Stackoverflow with a good description.

Comment: I don't know how else to describe what's happening. The code runs fine when I launch it as a local Python script. The executable created by PyInstaller is what croaks with no output whatsoever, and that's what I'm asking about here. Unfortunately I can't post the code itself as it's in a private GitHub repository. There is an issue posted here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4297

Comment: Best is to share it, it's too hard for an engineer to find the root cause... And I see you're trying to install a .zip file, can pip handle that?

Comment: Yes, the zip file being installed is the latest dev version of pyinstaller, it's recommended to try that before submitting an issue (unfortunately it didn't help me). If I share the (proprietary) code then I lose my job, not an option.

Comment: Can't you simply edit the company parts to make it publicly available? My support kind of ends here... You can also try other channels